in UBUNTU MATE 20.04 i want to set default pdf viewer app to open pdf in telegram app
my system ubuntu mate 20.04.06 .
I installed telegram (flatpak), then open a pdf in telegram, then a pop-up dialog box shown each time that name is "open with" pop-up dialog box
I want that when i click on pdf it open directly and don't show this annoying dialog box. please give me any effective solution.

Click on the message in telegram instead of clicking on Open With
